# UICollectionView Will Not Update Its Layout On Screen Rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UIView` with a `UICollectionView`.

On screen rotation I am trying to get the `UICollectionView` to stretch across the screen, and then redraw its cells.

After I had the data downloaded I tried both `[grid setNeedsLayout]` and `[grid setNeedsDisplay]` but that didn't work.

This is what I want to happen:

*Portrait*

[image]

*Landscape*

(This is also how it appears when the app is started in landscape, but if you change to portrait it doens't update.)

[image]

But this is what I get if I start in `Portrait` mode and switch to `Landscape`.

[image]

### I am creating these views programmatically. I am not using any Storyboards.

I have tried:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    grid = [[MyThumbnailGridView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];

}
```

I have also tried toying with:

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        //LANDSCAPE
        if(grid){
            NSLog(@"Grid Needs Landscape Layout");
            grid.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
            [grid refreshData];
        }

    }else {
        //PORTRIAT
        if(grid){
            NSLog(@"Grid Needs Portrait Layout");
            grid.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
            [grid refreshData];
        }
    }
}
```

**But I can't get it to stretch.**

*Any help?*

**MyThumbnailGridView**

```
@interface ViewController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate> {

    MyThumbnailGridView *grid;

    NSMutableArray * arrImages;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrImages = [NSMutableArray new];

    grid = [[MyThumbnailGridView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
    //grid = [[MyThumbnailGridView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    NSLog(@"showThumbnailGrid Grid View Size: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(grid.frame));

    [self.view addSubview:grid];

    [self getListOfImages];
}


-(void) getListOfImages {
        //Do background task to get images  and fill arrImages
         [self onDownloadImageDataComplete];    
}


- (void) onDownloadImageDataComplete{
    grid.imageDataSource = arrImages;
    //  [grid setNeedsLayout];
    //  [grid setNeedsDisplay];
}

//...
@end
```

***MyThumbnailGridView.h**

```
@interface MyThumbnailGridView : UIView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
-(void) refreshData;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *imageDataSource;

@end
```

***MyThumbnailGridView.m**

```
@interface MyThumbnailGridView () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>{
    UICollectionView *collectionView;
}

@end

@implementation MyThumbnailGridView


- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        [self customInit];

    }
    return self;
}
- (void) customInit {
    collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:[[MyFlowLayout alloc] init]];
    collectionView.delegate = self;
    collectionView.dataSource = self;
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    [collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [collectionView registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyId"];
    [self addSubview:collectionView];
}
- (void) refreshData {
    NSLog(@"Refresh Grid Data");
    [collectionView reloadData];
}

////other code
@end
```

**MyFlowLayout**

```
@interface MyFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
@end

@implementation MyFlowLayout
- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0;
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0;
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;

    }
    return self;
}

- (CGSize)itemSize {
    NSInteger numberOfColumns = 3;
    CGFloat itemWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame) - (numberOfColumns - 1)) / numberOfColumns;
    return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemWidth);
}

@end
```

**MyCollectionViewCell**

```
@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIImageView *imageView;
@end
@implementation MyCollectionViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.imageView = [UIImageView new];
        [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [self.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [self.imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.imageView.image = nil;
    [self.imageView setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.imageView setFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you try putting whatever you have in ```viewWillLayoutSubviews``` into ```viewDidLayoutSubviews```, and call super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() first in that method?

Comment: Just tried in ViewController, and it didn't help.

Comment: you should invalidate layout on the collection view

Comment: @user-44651 did you call ```[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];``` in the first line?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with
either you can change the frame of `MyThumbnailGridView`  view in delegate function of orientation or create the view with constraints like this

```
(void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];

    arrImages = [NSMutableArray new];

    grid = [[MyThumbnailGridView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];

    [self.view addSubview:grid];    

    [self getListOfImages];

 }

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{  
   if(Once){

        Once = NO;

       // adding constraints

  MyThumbnailGridView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

  [self.MyThumbnailGridView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:self.view.frame.size.width].active = YES;

  [self.MyThumbnailGridView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:self.view.frame.size.height/2].active = YES;

  [self.MyThumbnailGridView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;

  [self.MyThumbnailGridView.topAnchor  constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:self.view.frame.size.height/2].active = YES;



    }
}
```

Also implement this

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [MyThumbnailGridView.collectionView invalidate];
// Do view manipulation here.
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

Comment: That is Swift. I am using Obj-C

Comment: That didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the collection view itself is not changing size when the app rotates. You have given the collection view a fixed `frame` and then just walked away. So it never changes. So never lays itself out again.

You should give your MyThumbnailGridView and its collection view subview *autolayout contraints* to their superviews, so that they change size correctly when the app rotates.